# How does a middle-aged person know when he is over-exercising?

Tags: exercise, recovery, overtraining

The middle-aged person is in his early 40s. His sole purpose of exercising is to keep healthy. Looking good and having an attractive body is not a concern. Over-exercising can lead to damage of body parts, particularly when the person is no longer young. How does a a middle-aged person know when he is over-exercising to the extent that he is wearing off his body parts? Body aching?

Comment: Is there really that much to be concerned about? Start slowly, watch your form, don’t do stupid stuff like exercising while you’ve got a cold.